# Is there a way to limit the hints stored for a Cassandra node?

Tags: cassandra

In a situation where a node keeps going up and down (for example, becomes temporarily unresponsive due to GC), is there a way to limit the the hints stored for the problematic node to prevent build up of hints files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to limit the size of hints for a node that is unresponsive or unreachable by specifying a maximum size per node in `cassandra.yaml`. For example:

```
max_hints_size_per_host: 1024MiB
```

Note that this needs to be set on all nodes and will require a restart to take effect. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Another good `cassandra.yaml` setting for limiting hint build-up is the `max_hint_window_in_ms`.  By default, it is set to capture hints for 3 hours of node downtime.  But it can be adjusted to suit your needs.

```
max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000 # 3 hours
```

Per Erick's note above, this will *also* need to set per node and require a restart.